# How to prove basic lemmas about divisibility in Coq?

Tags: coq

```ml
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope Z_scope.


Lemma mod_mult_or : forall a b c, (a | b) \/ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
intros.
destruct H as [H1|H2].
apply Zdivide_mult_l; assumption.
apply Zdivide_mult_r; assumption.
Qed.


Lemma mod_mult : forall a b c, (a | b) /\ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
intros a b c [Hab Hac].
apply Z_divide_mul.
apply Hab.
apply Hac.
Qed.

Close Scope Z_scope.
```

I keep getting all sorts of errors on both proofs. I am not quite sure how to solve each proof the correct way. If someone can help me thanks!

Comment: Have you tried importing Coq.ZArith.Znumtheory.?

Comment: I am trying to approach it strictly with the ZArith library and using Z_scope.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make  the quotient explicit in a relation `a | b` (defined through an existential quantifier).

```
Lemma mod_mult_or : forall a b c, (a | b) \/ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H as [[q1 H1] | [q2 H2]].
  - exists (q1 * c).
    subst.  repeat rewrite <- Z.mul_assoc.  
    f_equal; now rewrite (Z.mul_comm  a c). 
  - 
 
Qed.
```

Comment: ```Lemma mod_mult_or : forall a b c, (a | b) \/ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
  intros a b c H. destruct H as [Hb | Hc].
  - apply Z.divide_mul_r. exact Hb.
  - apply Z.divide_mul_l. exact Hc.
Qed.
``` I tried this way but it seems to have not worked. :(

Comment: I edited the first sub-goal of the proof. What was the issue with it?

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: Just used unfold rewrite exists -> tactic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Coq are you using? This should work:

```ml
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope Z_scope.


Lemma mod_mult_or : forall a b c, (a | b) \/ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
intros.
destruct H as [H1|H2].
Search (_ | _ * _).
apply Z.divide_mul_l; assumption.
apply Z.divide_mul_r; assumption.
Qed.

Lemma mod_mult : forall a b c, (a | b) /\ (a | c) -> (a | b * c).
Proof.
intros a b c [Hab Hac].
apply mod_mult_or.
left.
apply Hab.
Qed.

Close Scope Z_scope.
```